# Optimize calls to exteral Api from getServerSideProps

Tags: next.js, server-side-rendering

Assume I have the following page in my next.js react application:

```js
// Filename: [mypath].jsx

export default function MyPage(props) {
    return (
        <>
            <Link href="/siteX">
                <a>Go to siteX</a>
            </Link>

            <Link href="/siteY">
                <a>Go to siteY</a>
            </Link>

            <div>{props.data.text}</div>
        </>
    );
}

export async function getServerSideProps(context) {
    const mypath = context.params.mypath;

    const res = await fetch(`https://external-api/${mypath}`)
    const data = await res.json();

    return { props: { data } };
}
```

When I access http://localhost:3000/siteX/ on server side the string `siteX` from the url is used for a call to an external (!) api on a different system, e.g. https://external-api/siteX. This works fine so far, but I see the following performance issue:

In the browser, when I click on a `<Link>`, two requests are happening: One to my own server to update `getServerSideProps` with the new path and a second one from my server to https://external-api/... to fetch the new data.

Do you see a way to optimize this? What I want is:

- when clicking on `<Link>` there is only one request directly to https://external-api/... happening and `data` is updated directly (e.g. as a state of MyPage).
- As it is now, when accessing http://localhost:3000/siteX/ the server should fetch the data and prerender the site

I could of course treat `data` as a state of `<MyPage>` and simply call a function to update it with a request when `<Link>` is clicked. But I also want a correct routing, history and so on.

Can you help me with that? Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some more resesarch I came across a solution. The next.js `<Link>` component has a property `shallow` that I can set to prevent the execution of `getServersideProps`. That way I can query the new data manually when a link is clicked. Still the initial data query is done by `getServersideProps` on the server and my intial SSR is working as before.

```js
// Filename: [mypath].jsx

export default function MyPage(props) {
    const [data, setData] = useState(props.data);

    function updateData(path) {
        const res = await fetch(`https://external-api/${path}`)
        const data = await res.json();
        setData(data);
    }

    return (
        <>
            <!-- Manually query and set data -->
            <div onClick={() => updateData("siteX")}>

                <!-- Trigger routing, but don't execute getServerSideProps (because of shallow={true}) -->
                <Link href="/siteX" shallow={true}>
                    <a>Go to siteX</a>
                </Link>

            </div>

            <div onClick={() => updateData("siteY")}>
                <Link href="/siteY" shallow={true}>
                    <a>Go to siteY</a>
                </Link>
            </div>

            <div>{props.data.text}</div>
        </>
    );
}

// If page is requested directly via url (and not because a <Link> element has been clicked) do SSR as before
export async function getServerSideProps(context) {
    const mypath = context.params.mypath;

    const res = await fetch(`https://external-api/${mypath}`)
    const data = await res.json();

    return { props: { data } };
}
```